# Playwright can't fill numbers only inputs

Tags: python, browser-automation, playwright

I'm testing a chromium playwright script on a shopping site. I have an issue with an input that accepts only numbers. If letters are added the input ignores them. The problem is here that playwright with its default fill:

```
page.locator("input xpath adress").fill('12.15')
```

Doesn't send numbers, although the string is made of numbers which selenium does if strings are given in send.keys.

I first thought that Playwright skips the input box. I discovered that this is the issue by testing keyboard number typing, so things like:

```
page.keyboard.press('Digit5')
```

Are accepted. What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: is this input accept dot `.`? Maybe better show URL for this page and create minimal working code which we could test.

Comment: Yes, the input accepts dot as well, and when only dot as string is entered, like fill('.'), it won't trigger anything as well, which it normally should. I tried all keys on my keyboard manually, and it seems that only digits 0 to 9 and dot and comma signs are accepted. All other characters are not displayed. So it won't cause any error for the input, Playwright accepts that it filled the input box with the string, but can't continue because no number was entered, which would activate the next button to be clicked.

Comment: I'm not having any issues using .type(number_to_type, { delay: any_delay )) in TypeScript with inputs that accept numbers only. Could you provide the URL and input?

Comment: Changing .fill(number) to .type(number) solved it for some reason. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Did anybody find a solution to this situation? 
Unfortunately, fill(number.toString()) doesn't work on my side.

Answer (score 1):

I had a the same problem:

```
page.fill("input.gdg-input", "1.1")
```

would not set the input value if the input field's mode is numeric, i.e. `<input class="gdg-input" type="text" value="" inputmode="numeric">`
I suspect that the reason is that `fill()` takes only string types, which is ignored by the numeric input field.

As suggested by @Donnerhorn, using [`page.type`](https://www.cuketest.com/playwright/docs/input#type-characters) solves the problem, because it emulates the user typing rather than passing the input a string value.

```
page.type("input.gdg-input", "1.1")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `page.type` is deprecated.

Comment: `type` is deprecated, but you can use `pressSequentially` instead. Still not working for me with a `PhoneInput` from the `react-phone-input-2` library, though...

Answer (score 1):

Adding `{force:true}` option worked for me in typescript, could maybe work in python as well -

```
page.locator('input xpath adress').fill('2',{force:true});
```